# WebView using GET cache for PUT

Tags: android, webview

I have a URL to which a GET request is first made, then subsequest PUT to update it. A WebView, however, caches the GET response and presents it when the PUT is made, effectively making the PUT redundant. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was caching too aggressively. Removing the following 
line fixes this:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```